# How to set the messages.xlf output location when running Angular i18n?

Tags: angular, angular-i18n

I'm using [angular's i18n tools](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/i18n.html) and have moved the messages.xlf output to a different folder than the default location (a new directory: `\app\locale`), as suggested.

When I rerun

```
>npm run i18n
```

even in the newly added app/locale directory, the `messages.xlf` file is output to the default location.

How can I specify where the output `messages.xlf` file is output to prevent having to move it around each time I regenerate it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a new option to your tsconfig.json to tell the angular compiler where to output the file.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    //your normal options...
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "genDir": "./app/locale"
  }
}
```

When you execute the i18n program make sure to include the tsconfig.json location.

```
node_modules\.bin>ng-xi18n -p ../../src/tsconfig.json
```

Comment: Great! This is getting picked up by `npm run i18n` and not affecting the typescript compilation. I'll keep an eye out to see if any other files get output to that location.

Answer (score 1):

Is this useful? Feel it's more than a simple code sample
http://rolandoldengarm.com/index.php/2016/10/17/angular-2-automated-i18n-workflow-using-gulp/

The useful aspect of this answer is Roland Oldengarm's gulp commands that take the output of the i18n and merges into the specified locale messages.xlf files automatically:

> I’m using a couple of gulp plugins, you’ll need to add as devDependencies with:

```
npm i --save-dev gulp-cheerio gulp-modify-file gulp-rename gulp-run merge-stream run-sequence
```

> The final set of gulp tasks:
>       var sourceElements = [];
>       gulp.task('i18n-get-source', function() {
>        return gulp.src('./src/i18n/messages.en.xlf')
>        .pipe(cheerio({
>        run: function ($, file) {

```
 $('trans-unit').each(function() { 
 sourceElements.push($(this));
 }); 
 },
 parserOptions: {
 xmlMode: true
 }
 }));
});

gulp.task('i18n-merge-to-translations', ['i18n-get-source'], function() {
 var languages = ['zh'];
 var tasks = [];
 for(var language of languages) {
 var path = "./src/i18n/messages." + language + ".xlf";
 tasks.push(
 gulp.src(path)
 .pipe(cheerio({
 run: function ($, file) {
 var sourceIds = [];
 for (var sourceElement of sourceElements) {
 var id = $(sourceElement).attr('id');
 sourceIds.push(id);
 var targetElement = $('#' + id);
 if (targetElement.length == 0) {
 // missing translation
 $('body').append(sourceElement);
 }
 }
 // now remove all redundant elements (i.e. removed)
 $('trans-unit').map((function() {
 var id = $(this).attr('id');
 var existing = sourceIds.find((item) => { return item == id} );

 if (!existing) {
 console.log("REMOVING");
 // remove it 
 $('#' + id).remove(); 
 } 
 }));


 } ,
 parserOptions: {
 xmlMode: true
 } 
 }))
 .pipe(gulp.dest('./src/i18n')));
 }
 return mergeStream(tasks);
})


// run ng-xi18n
gulp.task('i18n-extract-xlf', function() {
 return run('ng-xi18n').exec();
});



// create .ts files for all .xlf files so we can import it 
gulp.task('i18n-xlf2ts', function () {
 return gulp.src("./src/i18n/*.xlf")
 .pipe(rename(function (path) {
 path.extname = ".ts"
 }))
 .pipe(modifyFile(function (content, path, file) {
 var filename = path.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, '')
 var language = filename.split(".")[1].toUpperCase();
 return "export const TRANSLATION_" + language + " = `" + content + "`;";
 }))
 .pipe(gulp.dest("./src/i18n"));
});

// copy all source values to the target value as a default translation and make that our English translation
gulp.task('i18n-default', function() {
 return gulp.src('./messages.xlf')
 .pipe(cheerio({
 run: function ($, file) {
 // Each file will be run through cheerio and each corresponding `$` will be passed here.
 // `file` is the gulp file object

 $('source').each(function() {
 var source = $(this);
 var target = source.parent().find('target');
 //source.text(source.text().toUpperCase());
 target.html(source.html());
 }); 
 },
 parserOptions: {
 xmlMode: true
 }

 }))
 .pipe(rename('messages.en.xlf'))
 .pipe(gulp.dest("./src/i18n"))
});
```

Comment: **Never** provide just a link on an answer.